# Undertow worker threads changing? (Threadlocal allowed?)

Tags: java, multithreading, undertow

When I dispatch a Runnable or HttpHandler to a worker thread with undertow,
can I be sure that **run** or **handleRequest** are executed only in this thread?
I want to use a ThreadLocal(I am aware of required propagation and that InheritableThreadLocal will not work) to store scope local data in it.

My basic conception is that this worker thread will only execute my runnable/handler and not stall it.
I am only a little confused about involved IO via eg. a ResourceHandler.

Comment: AFAIK, if the exchange is in blocking mode then 1 worker thread will be used per request until the response is sent. However, Undertow allows for asynchronous IOs (RequestReceiver and ResponseSender APIs). If you use these APIs, you can no longer rely on having 1 request being handled solely by 1 worker thread. I can elaborate in an answer if you are interested...

Comment: @aramaki please elaborate.